# Tweaking a Function in Python

Tags: function

I am trying to get the following code to do a few more tricks:

```
    class App(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.grid()
            self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):

            self.answerLabel = Label(self, text="Output List:")
            self.answerLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

        def psiFunction(self):
            j = int(self.indexEntry.get())
            valueList = list(self.listEntry.get())
            x = map(int, valueList)
            if x[0] != 0:
                x.insert(0, 0)
            rtn = []
            for n2 in range(0, len(x) * j - 2):
                n = n2 / j
                r = n2 - n * j
                rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
            self.answer = Label(self, text=rtn)
            self.answer.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = Tk()
```

In particular, I am trying to get it to calculate len(x) * j - 1 terms, and to work for a variety of parameter values.  If you try running it you should find that you get errors for larger parameter values.  For example with a list 0,1,2,3,4 and a parameter j=3 we should run through the program and get 0123456789101112.  However, I get an error that the last value is 'out of range' if I try to compute it.

I believe it's an issue with my function as defined.  It seems the issue with parameters has something to do with the way it ties the parameter to the n value.  Consider 0123.  It works great if I use 2 as my parameter (called index in the function) but fails if I use 3.

EDIT:

```
def psi_j(x, j):
      rtn = []
      for n2 in range(0, len(x) * j - 2):
        n = n2 / j
        r = n2 - n * j
      if r == 0:
        rtn.append(j * x[n])
       else:
        rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
        print 'n2 =', n2, ': n =', n, ' r =' , r, ' rtn =', rtn
      return rtn
```

For example if we have psi_j(x,2) with x = [0,1,2,3,4] we will be able to get [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] with an error on 12.

The idea though is that we should be able to calculate that last term.  It is the 12th term of our output sequence, and 12 = 3*4+0 => 3*x[4] + 0*(x[n+1]-x[n]).  Now, there is no 5th term to calculate so that's definitely an issue but we do not need that term since the second part of the equation is zero.  Is there a way to write this into the equation?

Comment: Please remove any irrelevant code, such as `indexEntry`.  Shorter code is easier to read, and easier to find the problem in.

Comment: @FakeRain I removed some of the self.entry lines as well.  I was worried that removing some things might obscure the idea.  If there's more you believe I can delete please let me know and I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: It may be helpful if you print out the values of the variables during a program run and compare them with your expectations. It may as well be helpful to test such quite complex functions without too much overhead, e. g. the GUI.

Comment: It's a fine line, but no scroll bars is usually the target :-)

Comment: @glglgl Sorry glglgl, what do you mean?  In the case where I receive errors rather than values wouldn't I have no method of comparison?  In cases where the GUI works properly the results are the same as the results from the function block of code.  It may help to clarify that the GUI was built around the function after it had already been tested.  However, at that time I accepted it as a fact of life that I would be missing the last value.  Unfortunately with the GUI there is now an issue with using certain combinations of parameters and lists.

Comment: If you try running the function alone you will find that by taking any input x = [0,1,2,3,4,5] (for example) and psi_j(x,3)  (where j=3 as an example) everything goes smoothly.  I may be misunderstanding though.

Comment: Obviously you did something wrong on the conversion. In order to separate between GUI and logic, you should have let the original function in place and call it from the GUI stuff. Could you show us the original function?

Comment: @glglgl Sorry about that, I've included it in the original post.

Comment: `print psi_j([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 3)` gives me an error as well...

Comment: @glglgl Sorry, you need to have x = [0,1,2,3,4] and psi_j(x,2) on separate lines after using the definition.

Comment: @Stopwatch Why should separate lines be needed? And what now, 2 or 3?

Comment: @glglgl Sorry, 3.  I was giving an example but I should have made it consistent with the above.

Comment: @glglgl Would it be worthwhile to make another post with an updated version of this code based on FakeRain's edits?  I implemented his suggestions with my large block of code above and it gave me only the last number of the output.  Do you have any suggestions for how to make it output every number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding that the purpose of the function is (is it a kind of filter? or smoothing function?), I prickled it out of the GUI suff and tested it alone:

```
def psiFunction(j, valueList):
    x = map(int, valueList)
    if x[0] != 0:
        x.insert(0, 0)
    rtn = []
    for n2 in range(0, len(x) * j - 2):
        n = n2 / j
        r = n2 - n * j
        print "n =", n, "max_n2 =", len(x) * j - 2, "n2 =", n2, "lx =", len(x), "r =", r
        val = j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n])
        rtn.append(val)
        print  j * x[n], r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]), val
    return rtn

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print psiFunction(3, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Calling this module leads to some debugging output and, at the end, the mentionned error message.

Obviously, your `x[n + 1]` access fails, as `n` is `4` there, so `n + 1` is 5, one too much for accessing the `x` array, which has length 5 and thus indexes from 0 to 4.

EDIT: Your `psi_j()` gives me the same behaviour.

Let me continue guessing: Whatever we want to do, we have to ensure that `n + 1` stays below `len(x)`. So maybe a

```
for n2 in range(0, (len(x) - 1) * j):
```

would be helpful. It only produces the numbers 0..11, but I think this is the only thing which can be expected out of it: the last items only can be

```
3*3 + 0*(4-3)
3*3 + 1*(4-3)
3*3 + 2*(4-3)
```

and stop. And this is achieved with the limit I mention here.

Comment: I should specify, and maybe this was an issue originally, that we should be counting [0,1,2,3,4] as 4 terms.  So we have slot 0, slot 1...slot 4.  n should not be 4, however.  If we are calculating the 5th term of our output sequence we do so as follows:

n2 = 5 = 3*(1) + 2 = (running through the function) 3x[1] + 2(x[2]-x[1])

Comment: I think your solution is good but it looks like FakeRain's will get the final term as long as I can get it to work.  The issue is only that it seems to fail to list out every element as it did previously.

Comment: One issue I have is that as we increase the parameter values we lose more and more terms.  For example with a list [0,1,2,2,2,3,3] we get 20 terms out.

Answer (score 2):

If we think about the example data `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and a `j` of `3`, the problem is that we're trying to get `x[4`]` in the last iteration.

- `len(x) * j - 2` for this data is `10`
- `range(0, 10)` is 0 through 9.

Manually processing our last iteration, allows us to resolve the code to this.

```
n = 3 # or 9 / 3
r = 0 # or 9 - 3 * 3
rtn.append(3 * x[3] + 0 * (x[3 + 1] - x[3]))
```

We have code trying to reach `x[3 + 1]`, which doesn't exist when we only have indices 0 through 3.

To fix this, we could rewrite the code like this.

```
n = n2 / j
r = n2 - n * j
if r == 0:
    rtn.append(j * x[n])
else:
    rtn.append(j * x[n] + r * (x[n + 1] - x[n]))
```

If `r` is 0, then `(x[n + 1] - x[n])` is irrelevant.

Please correct me if my math is wrong on that.  I can't see a case where `n >= len(x)` and `r != 0`, but if that's possible, then my solution is invalid.

Comment: Since len(x) includes zero you are correct. So [0,1,2,3,4] has length 5 and there will never be a case where we need to use x[5] and r!=0.  I think your solution works perfectly.

Comment: However, I do get an issue when I try to run it.  Not an error but it simply prints one number.  Does my adaptation of your code in my original post look fine?